# accumulate and ostringstream compile error

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following compile error in the marked lines:

> error: conversion from ‘`std::basic_ostream<char,
>   std::char_traits<char> >`’ to non-scalar type ‘`std::ostringstream`’
>   requested

Could you help me to correct my example?

```
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

ostringstream ConvertLettersToNumbers(ostringstream acc, char input)
{
    if(isdigit(input))
    {
        return acc << input; // error
    }
    else
    {
        return acc << static_cast<int>(input); // error
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string stringToCovert = "ABC";

    ostringstream out = accumulate(stringToCovert.begin(), stringToCovert.end(),     
         string(), ConvertLettersToNumbers);

    string convertedString = out.str(); // expected "656667"

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: My first version using strings that works but is slow:

```
   string ConvertLettersToNumbers(string acc, char input)
    {
        if(isdigit(input))
        {
            return acc + input;
        }
        else
        {
            stringstream sstr;
            sstr << static_cast<int>(input);
            return acc + sstr.str();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can this really work with `accumulate`? I would figure you need the return value of your function to be assignable to `std::string`. AFAIK `std::ostringstream` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different algorithm. You don't want to add elements together (that is what `accumulate` is for), you want to `transform` your sequence into another kind of sequence.

Consider this approach:

```
int ConvertLetterToNumber(char input)
{
    if(std::isdigit(input))
    {
        return input - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string stringToConvert = "ABC";
    std::ostringstream stream;
    std::transform(stringToConvert.begin(),
            stringToConvert.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(stream),
            ConvertLetterToNumber);

    std::string convertedString = stream.str();

    return 0;
}
```

For a working sample see [here](http://ideone.com/vaaHE)

Comment: I compared the performance of the two solutions using `transform` Vs `accumulate` algorithmns and they take about the same time.

Comment: A possible optimization might be to avoid using strings and just put ints to the stream directly ... I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `acc << input` is `std::ostream&`. You lose the concrete type of the original stream. You can fix that with a cast:

```
return static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(acc << input);
```

---

If this comes up a lot, you could imagine a variadically templated helper:

```
return covariant_stream(acc, input, input2, "separator", input3);
```

---

Since your code has many other errors, here's a fixed skeleton:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>

#define using abusing

std::ostringstream & ConvertLettersToNumbers(std::ostringstream & acc, char input)
{
    return static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(acc << input);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to change my call of `accumulate` too? It doesn't compile after adding the two casts and I get huge template errors.

Comment: @nabulke: Those errors are unrelated. You mustn't take `acc` by value, but rather by reference, and you must also return a reference. I added an example.

Comment: @KerrekSB but how can this work? `accumulate` will do something like `sum = ConvertLettersToNumbers(sum, *it);` for each element in the string. And the type of sum is `std::string`.

Comment: @nabulke The type of the `sum` is inferred from third argument to `accumulate` - there you say `string()`

Comment: @Fiktik: Ah, sorry. I was talking about my example code in ideone (check my link in previous comment)

Comment: Better yet, use `ostringstream& ConvertLettersToNumbers(ostringstream& acc, char input)` to pass by reference instead of passing by value.

Comment: @nabulke ok, but the problem is still there - streams are not copy constructible, as the first error says - the base class `ios_base` has private copy constructor. In c++11 this would probably work because of move semantics, but in c++03 this is imho not possible. You could get around the copy by using `std::cref`, but you can't get around missing assignment operator on streams.

Comment: @nabulke: I think you want to change your function signature to return `std::string`, and say `static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(acc << input).str();`. But actually you want to throw out everything and just write the whole thing with strings and chars, and no streams at all, I'd say.

Comment: @twalberg: That's what I am doing - check my example here [ideone](http://ideone.com/3RRAI)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I had it all working with strings, _but_ it was really slow in my use case. My profiler told me the string concatenations require a lot of time, therefore I was looking for a solutions using the underlying streams directly.

Comment: @nabulke: I can still see the word "stream" everywhere. I think that needs to die.

Comment: @nabulke: There are no "underlying streams". On the contrary, the string stream has an underlying *string*!

Comment: I edited my question and added the `string` version that works (thats where I got the notion of using stream directly to make it faster).